# Python Script Ending only Sometimes

Tags: python

I'm finishing up a python script that essentially works as an alarm clock, with a youtube video opening up when the alarm goes off. This is what I have so far, and for the most part it works perfectly:

```
import time
import webbrowser
import random
import sys

def addVideo():
    videoToAdd = raw_input("Enter the url of the video to add: ")
    with open('alarmVideos.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(videoToAdd + '\n')

def pickVideo():
    with open('alarmVideos.txt') as file:
        videosToUse = file.readlines()
    useVideo = random.choice(videosToUse)
    return useVideo


alarmTime = raw_input("When would you like to set your alarm to?: \nPlease use this format: 01:00 (24hr clock)\n")
localTime = time.strftime("%H:%M") 

add_Video = raw_input("Would you like to add a video to your list? (y/n): \n")

if add_Video == 'y':
    addVideo()

print "Your alarm is set to:", alarmTime

while alarmTime != localTime:
    localTime = time.strftime("%H:%M") 
    time.sleep(1)

if alarmTime == localTime:
    controller = webbrowser.get()
    controller.open(pickVideo())
    sys.exit()
```

However, the script only ends if I have a browser open already and the video opens up in a new tab. If I have chrome closed when the alarm goes off, the video will open up in a new window, but the script does not end. I'm not sure why. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't know much about the libraries, but is it possible, that `webbrowser.get()` starts a new browser window if none exists? This could mean, that your script "owns" that browser process and runs as long as the window is open.

Comment: Even when I close the browser that is opened by the script, the script continues to run but not do anything.

Comment: Which Python Version do you have? According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html) Chromium/Chrome support has been added in 2.7.5 - if you have an older version this might explain the issue.

Comment: I just tried your script and it ended correctly in a new window (Edge, Python 3.4).

Comment: I've got a newer version but I actually found a solution that involves threading

Comment: You create a new thread that uses webbrowser to open a new window. The same solution also said that you can use fork easily in any os but windows

Comment: Okay and now it is working with my original code... Thank you guys for your help though!